# WooCommerce wrong product item counts and meta data added in order

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

For about two weeks now I have the surreal problem that almost every order has the correct items but wrong meta datas and the ordered number of items are changed like 3-20 instead of just one.

I had a bloated database on my shared server and it was full. I cleared the wp_actionscheduler_logs to get enough space back and cleared the wp_actionscheduler_actions entries (completed, failed, aborted).

Since that I have the problem. Already made a staging testsite but it still continues. Debugging is active but it only shows problem with the Pixelyoursite plugin which I deactivated but nothing changed.

Is there any chance to check the database for double entries or something like that?

Already tested a different theme
Already deactivated all plugins (one by one)
Tested with existing and completely new products
Tested as a guest and test account
Same effect by using coupons

WC version 8.1.1
WP version 6.3.1
WC payment solution (only Paypal Checkout)
Theme Jupiter X (5.3.1)
PHP version 8.1 (currently 7.4 for testing)

Comment: Its unclear when you face the issue. On order creation or when someone using coupons ? And the problem is in the quantity of products ? Is your total correct ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, if I use a coupon or not, it's right after I "successfully purchased" an order. When I go into the order details, I can see what I put in my cart which was correct. Yes, it's the quantity of the products, the total is correct.

Comment: Firstly, check if there is an error on the WooCommerce Logs. You can check **System Status:** You can find it via WooCommerce > Status. Select “Get system report”. To check **Error log:** See the fatal error log found under WooCommerce > System Status > Logs (if available).

Comment: Unfortunately there are just error logs about Pixelyoursite and that's all. I already deactivated it and it's still deactivated, so no errors since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to completely shut off the whole shop and build it from scratch by using a backup some weeks before the mess started.

After the database bloat there where 27 failed orders I couldn't see, because they where kind of lost and nowhere listed. I only noticed it by checking the gap in the order numbers between WooCommerce and PayPal. Because of that, I assume that the numbers of the failed orders where given to other, later incoming, orders after I deleted the wp_actionscheduler_actions and wp_actionscheduler_log databases.

The new orders with these 27 order numbers where visible but not the old orders with the same numbers. After the customer paid with PayPal, there must have been a mix-up between these numbers and it went on...like all orders get there stuff PLUS each the stuff from the previous 27th order.

Why? Because Paypal counts every order on its own. It's an ongoing process. Again, it's a supposition but that's the only plausible thing I could find out.

What I did beside rebuilding the shop: I used a small plugin that allowed me to start with a new order number and since then everything works. The mess ended with order number 76224 and I continued with the order number 100000 .